# Multiple input() statements skip lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.5.1 and I've had this problem with a few scripts. When I have multiple `input()` lines in a row, the ipython window will skip lines in between them. Here's my code:

```
def DMScalc(D, M, S):
    if D < 0.:
        DD = D + M*(-1)/60 + S*(-1)/3600
    else:
        DD = D + M/60 + S/3600
    return DD

print("\nConvert Degrees-Minutes-Seconds to Decimal Degrees")
D = float(input("Degrees: "))
M = float(input("Minutes: "))
S = float(input("Seconds: "))
print('Decimal Degrees:', end=' ')
print(DMScalc(D, M, S))
```

The ipython window shows the following:

```
Convert Degrees-Minutes-Seconds to Decimal Degrees

Degrees: 33

Minutes: 29

Seconds: 38
Decimal Degrees: 33.49388888888889
```

I'd like to remove the skipped lines above Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds so the end result is this:

```
Convert Degrees-Minutes-Seconds to Decimal Degrees
Degrees: 33
Minutes: 29
Seconds: 38
Decimal Degrees: 33.49388888888889
```

I checked the documentation for `input()` and it only talks about a *trailing* newline, which I don't think is the problem here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with python 3.5.1 on windows. I tried `python script.py` and `ipython script.py`. None added additional newlines. How did you start your script?

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem in python 3.4.3

Comment: @Wombatz I edited the post to include my entire script. Also, I'm using Spyder IDE if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce using python 3.5.1 and ipython 5 on Arch Linux. It's probably Spyder IDE

Comment: cannot reproduce in python 2.7 using raw_input either

Comment: Yeah, just tried it via command line and it doesn't produce the blank lines -- must be Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

With the `input()` function alone you can't.

Try the [Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) library so you can take more control of terminal behaviour, because `input()` will always give you a new line.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question?

Comment: The issue is that the new line that appears in not Python's issue. It is the terminal emulator that inserts it when he presses enter anter inserting some input.

Comment: I'm not sure how curses is really going to help within IPython and Spyder.

Comment: Hm yes your'e right, it's useless in IPython's console. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos Cordoba, a Spyder developer, says this is a bug in their IPython console, see here:

[How can I prevent Python from inserting a new line after taking user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667227/how-can-i-prevent-python-from-inserting-a-new-line-after-taking-user-input)

You might check their Github repo to see if it has been fixed.

Here's the issue page if you're curious: https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/262